# How to redirect with custom header using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I make this kind of request for login, sending username and password and receiving a token:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginForm").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./login",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(e) {
          window.location.href = e['redirect_url']
          localStorage.setItem("token", e['token'])
          alert('redirected')
          return false
      }
    })

  })
})
```

and I want the redirect to use `{'Authorization': 'Token '+localStorage.getItem('token')}` in headers, because the redirect URL requires authorization. How do I alter the header in redirect? Or is there another way around?

Comment: you already try with this? window.location.href=”login?token=”+e['token'];

Comment: yes, it works but it doesn't seem secure to pass the token within URL

Comment: @Zygro did you find solution this issue? can you post that so that others can use it?

Comment: I think I have just used a different authorization method, sorry